# MLLib Scala ArrayIndexOutOfBoundException when MaxBins >= maximum num of categories

Tags: scala, apache-spark, decision-tree

I am learning how to use MLLib and I encountered an ArrayOutOfBoundException when maxBins >= maximum number of categories for a feature.

I use a dataset (on animal shelter) from kaggle.com with the following headers 
AnimalID    Name    DateTime    OutcomeType OutcomeSubtype  AnimalType  SexuponOutcome  AgeuponOutcome  Breed   Color

For breed I have 1381 categories.
When using Spark DecisionTree.trainClassifier, if maxBins < 1381, I get an exception that the maxBins should be at least 1381.
When I put maxBins >= 1381, I get an ArrayOutOfBoundException.

```
   val model = DecisionTree.trainClassifier(trainingData,
      numClasses=numClasses,
      AnimalModel.categoricalFeaturesInfo(),
      impurity=impurity,
      maxDepth = a,
      maxBins=maxBins
      )
```

Exception

```
   java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 5
       at org.apache.spark.mllib.tree.impl.DecisionTreeMetadata$$anonfun$buildMetadata$4.apply(DecisionTreeMetadata.scala:167)
at org.apache.spark.mllib.tree.impl.DecisionTreeMetadata$$anonfun$buildMetadata$4.apply(DecisionTreeMetadata.scala:164)
at scala.collection.immutable.HashMap$HashMap1.foreach(HashMap.scala:224)
```

The dataset has 26739 rows

Comment: maxbins must really be greater than the number of categories for the DecisionTree learning to work. The maxbin exception is simply a check that is done. The ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException is likely not related at all to the maxbins value. Possibly something is wrong with the dataset.